# olumn not found: 1054 Unknown column 'empleos.titular_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Necesito realizar una consulta a una tabla de Titular que tiene relacion con otra table de Empleos. Intento usar **`with`** en la consulta.

Una persona puede tener varios empleos. Este es el modelo de Titular:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \App\Models\Empleo;

class Titular extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $table = 'titulares';


        public function empleos()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Empleo::class);
        }
}
```

Este es el Modelo de Empleo

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \App\Models\Titular;

class Empleo extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


    public function titular()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Titular::class);
    }
}
```

El Controlador

```
public function show(Titular $titular)
{
   $t = Titular::with('empleos')
        ->where('titulares.id', '=', $titular->id)
        ->get();
   return $t;
}
```

Error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
> 1054 Unknown column 'empleos.titular_id' in 'where clause' (SQL:
> select * from `empleos` where `empleos`.`titular_id` in (1) and
> `empleos`.`deleted_at` is null) in file ......

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'empleos.titular_id'

Nos esta indicando que una columna que sería la llave foránea en la entidad `Empleo`:

- No existe (es decir no esta declarada)
- Si existe es decir si esta declarada, pero el nombre no coincide con la convención de nombres que espera encontrar [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Para solucionar esto, debería alcanzar con agregar lo siguiente en la relaciones definidas:

```
    public function empleos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Empleo::class, 'llave_foranea');
    }


    public function titular()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Titular::class, 'llave_foranea');
    }
```

Es decir como notas al método le podemos pasar un segundo argumento el cual sería un *string* con el nombre de la llave foránea.

Por cierto y tal vez como algo extra, a tu consulta puedes hacerle las siguientes modificaciones:

```
$t = Titular::with('empleos')
        ->whereId($titular->id)
        ->first();
```

- Podemos omitir indicar en el `where` el nombre de la entidad de la cual planeamos filtrar, ya que este método trabajaría con la entidad `Titular`
- Si solo planeas traer un registro, entonces no tiene caso que tu resultado sea una colección y podemos omitir el uso del método `get` por el del método `first`

**Referencia**

- [Relación uno a muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)